# Login API for McAfee ESM server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mcafee

I installed McAfee ESM 10.2  server in my windows machine with VMware workstation pro.
It's deployed properly and I am able to see the Dash Board and all after login.

I am accessing SIEM using below URL

> https://192.168.81.133/#/login.

I found  below URL, it has some API request

> https://192.168.81.133/rs/esm/help/

But We didn't find login API request to get login token/session to get data from ESMserver using other API like below

For alarm list ,event and etc..

> https://192.168.81.133/rs/esm/alarmGetTriggeredAlarms?triggeredTimeRange=CUSTOM&customStart=2018-02-21T05:01:16.438Z&customEnd=2018-02-21T05:01:16.438Z

if I access above URL without valid session it's giving

> Issue validating session token.

In the previous version 9.6 there is API for login POST request

> https://192.168.81.133/rs/esm/login.json

but this is not working in 10.2 vesrion

As I am new to McAfee ESM, can any help on this.
My questions  are

1 What is REST API for login?

Answer (score 1):

The login URL in McAfee ESM 10.2 had been changed,
and now it is https://x.x.x.x/rs/esm/login

You can find all the API commands on:
https://x.x.x.x/rs/esm/help

Answer (score 1):

The [McAfee SIEM API Python wrapper](https://github.com/mfesiem/msiempy) can handle of the boring stuff like login, get results rows, etc for you.

It's really simple to query events and perform other actions like managing Datasources.

Exemple of simple event query with filters :

```
from  msiempy.event import EventManager, FieldFilter

print('Simple event query sorted by AlertID')
events = EventManager(
        time_range='CURRENT_YEAR',
        fields=['SrcIP', 'AlertID'], # SrcIP and AlertID are not queried by default
        filters=[
                FieldFilter('DstIP', ['0.0.0.0/0',]),
                FieldFilter('HostID', ['mail'], operator='CONTAINS')], # Please replace "mail" by a test hostname
        order=(('ASCENDING', 'AlertID')),
        limit=10)

events.load_data()
print(events)
print(events.get_text(fields=['AlertID','LastTime','SrcIP', 'Rule.msg']))
```